# How to reposition the third string of each line to start at the nth character on the same line

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

Ubuntu 16.04
Bash 4.4.20

I'd like to clean up a few of my game configs so the information is neatly stored in columns. Each line has something like:

```
somegamevar  "0"       // This here explains the stuff on the left
anothervar    9        // Sometimes the value is not in doublequotes
```

When a file is not neatly columned, it can get messy so we spend a lot of time in an editor tabbing. Here is a section of one of the files.

```
mp_death_drop_defuser                       "1"             // Drop defuser on player death
mp_death_drop_grenade                       "2"             // Which grenade to drop on player death: 0=none, 1=best, 2=current or best
mp_death_drop_gun                           "1"     // Which gun to drop on player death: 0=none, 1=best, 2=current or best
mp_defuser_allocation                       "0"             // How to allocate defusers to CTs at start or round: 0=none, 1=random, 2=everyone
mp_do_warmup_period                         "1"             // Whether or not to do a warmup period at the start of a match.
mp_forcecamera                              "1"     // Restricts spectator modes for dead players
mp_force_pick_time                          "160"           // The amount of time a player has on the team screen to make a selection before being auto-teamed 
mp_free_armor                               "0"             // Determines whether armor and helmet are given automatically.
mp_freezetime                               "12"    // How many seconds to keep players frozen when the round starts
mp_friendlyfire             "1" // Allows team members to injure other members of their team
mp_halftime                                 "1"             // Determines whether or not the match has a team-swapping halftime event.
mp_halftime_duration                        "15"            // Number of seconds that halftime lasts
mp_join_grace_time                          "30"            // Number of seconds after round start to allow a player to join a game
mp_limitteams                               "0"             // Max # of players 1 team can have over another (0 disables check)
mp_logdetail                                "3"             // Logs attacks.  Values are: 0=off, 1=enemy, 2=teammate, 3=both)
mp_match_can_clinch                         "1"             // Can a team clinch and end the match by being so far ahead that the other team has no way to catching up
mp_match_end_restart                        "1"             // At the end of the match, perform a restart instead of loading a new map
mp_maxmoney                                 "16000"         // maximum amount of money allowed in a player's account
mp_maxrounds                                "30"            // max number of rounds to play before server changes maps
mp_molotovusedelay                          "0"             // Number of seconds to delay before the molotov can be used after acquiring it
mp_overtime_enable                          "1"             // Use overtime rules to determine winner 
mp_overtime_maxrounds                       "10"
mp_overtime_startmoney                      "16000"
mp_playercashawards                         "1"             // Players can earn money by performing in-game actions
mp_playerid                                 "0"             // Controls what information player see in the status bar: 0 all names; 1 team names; 2 no names 
mp_playerid_delay                           "0.5"           // Number of seconds to delay showing information in the status bar
mp_playerid_hold                            "0.25"          // Number of seconds to keep showing old information in the status bar
mp_round_restart_delay                      "5"             // Number of seconds to delay before restarting a round after a win
mp_roundtime                                "1.75"          // How many minutes each round takes.
mp_roundtime_defuse                         "1.75"          // How many minutes each round takes on defusal maps.
mp_solid_teammates                          "1"             // Determines whether teammates are solid or not.
mp_startmoney                               "800"           // amount of money each player gets when they reset
mp_teamcashawards                           "1"             // Teams can earn money by performing in-game actions
mp_timelimit                                "0"             // game time per map in minutes
mp_tkpunish                                 "0"             // Will a TK'er be punished in the next round?  {0=no,  1=yes}
mp_warmuptime                               "1"             // If true, there will be a warmup period/round at the start of each match to allow
mp_weapons_allow_map_placed                 "1"             // If this convar is set, when a match starts, the game will not delete weapons placed in the map.
mp_weapons_allow_zeus                       "1"             // Determines whether the Zeus is purchasable or not.
mp_win_panel_display_time                   "15"            // The amount of time to show the win panel between matches / halfs

spec_freeze_time                            "5.0"           // Time spend frozen in observer freeze cam.
spec_freeze_panel_extended_time             "0"             // Time spent with the freeze panel still up after observer freeze cam is done.

sv_accelerate                               "5.6"           // ( def. "10" ) client notify replicated 
sv_allow_votes                              "0"             // Allow voting?
sv_allow_wait_command                       "0"             // Allow or disallow the wait command on clients connected to this server.
sv_alltalk                              "0"             // Players can hear all other players' voice communication, no team restrictions
sv_alternateticks                           "0"             // If set, server only simulates entities on even numbered ticks.
sv_cheats                           "0"             // Allow cheats on server
sv_clockcorrection_msecs                    "15"            // The server tries to keep each player's m_nTickBase withing this many msecs of the server absolute tickcount
sv_consistency                      "0"             // Whether the server enforces file consistency for critical files
sv_contact                      "0"             // Contact email for server sysop
sv_damage_print_enable                      "1"             // Turn this off to disable the player's damage feed in the console after getting killed.
sv_dc_friends_reqd                          "0"             // Set this to 0 to allow direct connects to a game in progress even if no presents
sv_deadtalk                                 "1"             // Dead players can speak (voice, text) to the living
sv_forcepreload             "0"             // Force server side preloading.
sv_friction                             "4.8"           // World friction.
sv_full_alltalk                             "0"             // Any player (including Spectator team) can speak to any other player
sv_gameinstructor_disable                   "1"             // Force all clients to disable their game instructors.
sv_ignoregrenaderadio                       "0"             // Turn off Fire in the hole messages
sv_kick_players_with_cooldown               0               // (0: do not kick; 1: kick Untrusted players; 2: kick players with any cooldown)
sv_kick_ban_duration                        "0"     // How long should a kick ban from the server should last (in minutes)
sv_lan                                      "0"             // Server is a lan server ( no heartbeat, no authentication, no non-class C addresses )
sv_log_onefile                              "0"             // Log server information to only one file.
sv_logbans                                  "1"             // Log server bans in the server logs.
sv_logecho                                  "1"             // Echo log information to the console.
sv_logfile                                  "1"             // Log server information in the log file.
sv_logflush                                 "0"             // Flush the log file to disk on each write (slow).
sv_logsdir                                  "logfiles"      // Folder in the game directory where server logs will be stored.
sv_maxrate                                  "0"             // min. 0.000000 max. 30000.000000 replicated  Max bandwidth rate allowed on server, 0 == unlimited
```

`column -t` would be great if the third column wasn't there but that third column is important.

So this is the expected outcome:
Column 1 and 2 clearing each other by a few spaces.
Column 3 starting at the 70th character.

```
sv_alltalk                      "0"                                             // Players can hear all other players voice communication, no team restrictions
sv_alternateticks               "0"                                             // If set, server only simulates entities on even numbered ticks.
sv_cheats                       "0"                                             // Allow cheats on server
sv_clockcorrection_msecs        "15"                                            // The server tries to keep each players m_nTickBase withing this many msecs of the server absolute tickcount
sv_consistency                  "0"                                             // Whether the server enforces file consistency for critical files
sv_contact                      "0"                                             // Contact email for server sysop
sv_damage_print_enable          "1"                                             // Turn this off to disable the players damage feed in the console after getting killed.
sv_dc_friends_reqd              "0"                                             // Set this to 0 to allow direct connects to a game in progress even if no presents
sv_deadtalk                     "1"                                             // Dead players can speak (voice, text) to the living
sv_forcepreload                 "0"                                             // Force server side preloading.
sv_friction                     "4.8"                                           // World friction.
sv_full_alltalk                 "0"                                             // Any player (including Spectator team) can speak to any other player
sv_gameinstructor_disable       "1"                                             // Force all clients to disable their game instructors.
sv_ignoregrenaderadio           "0"                                             // Turn off Fire in the hole messages
sv_kick_players_with_cooldown   0                                               // (0: do not kick; 1: kick Untrusted players; 2: kick players with any cooldown)
sv_kick_ban_duration            "0"                                             // How long should a kick ban from the server should last (in minutes)
sv_lan                          "0"                                             // Server is a lan server ( no heartbeat, no authentication, no non-class C addresses )
sv_log_onefile                  "0"                                             // Log server information to only one file.
sv_logbans                      "1"                                             // Log server bans in the server logs.
sv_logecho                      "1"                                             // Echo log information to the console.
sv_logfile                      "1"                                             // Log server information in the log file.
sv_logflush                     "0"                                             // Flush the log file to disk on each write (slow).
sv_logsdir                      "logfiles"                                      // Folder in the game directory where server logs will be stored.
sv_maxrate                      "0"                                             // min. 0.000000 max. 30000.000000 replicated  Max bandwidth rate allowed on server, 0 == unlimited
```

As you can see above, column 1 and 2 are close to each other and column 3 is neatly to the right starting at the 70th column.

Comment: This has been accomplished above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    wid = (length($1) > wid ? length($1) : wid)
    next
}
NF {
    hd = sprintf("%-*s%3s%s", wid, $1, "", $2)
    tl = ( (s=index($0,"//")) ? substr($0,s) : "")
    $0 = sprintf("%-69s%s", hd, tl)
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
mp_death_drop_defuser    "1"                                         // Drop defuser on player death
mp_death_drop_gun        "1"                                         // Which gun to drop on player death: 0=none, 1=best, 2=current or best
mp_friendlyfire          "1"                                         // Allows team members to injure other members of their team
mp_halftime              "1"                                         // Determines whether or not the match has a team-swapping halftime event.
mp_overtime_startmoney   "16000"
mp_playercashawards      "1"                                         // Players can earn money by performing in-game actions

sv_alltalk               "0"                                         // Players can hear all other players' voice communication, no team restrictions
sv_cheats                "0"                                         // Allow cheats on server
sv_forcepreload          "0"                                         // Force server side preloading.
```

---

Original Answer:

This will start the 3rd column at character position 60 as you asked for:

```
awk '
    s = index($0,"//") {
        hd = substr($0,1,s-1)
        sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",hd)
        $0 = sprintf("%-59s%s",hd,substr($0,s))
    }
1' file
```

e.g. given this input:

```
$ cat file
mp_death_drop_defuser                       "1"             // Drop defuser on player death
mp_death_drop_gun                           "1"     // Which gun to drop on player death: 0=none, 1=best, 2=current or best
mp_friendlyfire             "1" // Allows team members to injure other members of their team
mp_halftime                                 "1"             // Determines whether or not the match has a team-swapping halftime event.
mp_overtime_startmoney                      "16000"
mp_playercashawards                         "1"             // Players can earn money by performing in-game actions

sv_alltalk                              "0"             // Players can hear all other players' voice communication, no team restrictions
sv_cheats                           "0"             // Allow cheats on server
sv_forcepreload             "0"             // Force server side preloading.
```

```
$ awk 's=index($0,"//"){hd=substr($0,1,s-1); sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",hd); $0=sprintf("%-59s%s",hd,substr($0,s))} 1' file
mp_death_drop_defuser                       "1"            // Drop defuser on player death
mp_death_drop_gun                           "1"            // Which gun to drop on player death: 0=none, 1=best, 2=current or best
mp_friendlyfire             "1"                            // Allows team members to injure other members of their team
mp_halftime                                 "1"            // Determines whether or not the match has a team-swapping halftime event.
mp_overtime_startmoney                      "16000"
mp_playercashawards                         "1"            // Players can earn money by performing in-game actions

sv_alltalk                              "0"                // Players can hear all other players' voice communication, no team restrictions
sv_cheats                           "0"                    // Allow cheats on server
sv_forcepreload             "0"                            // Force server side preloading.
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  first_len=(first_len>length($1)?first_len:length($1))
  second_len=(second_len>length($2)?second_len:length($2))
  next
}
{
  val=""
  match($0,/\/\/.*/)
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
  printf("%-"first_len"s\t\t%-"second_len"s\t\t%s\n",$1,$2,val)
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                              ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                                           ##Checking condition when Input_file is being read first time.
  first_len=(first_len>length($1)?first_len:length($1))            ##Creating first_len which has length of 1st field.
  second_len=(second_len>length($2)?second_len:length($2))         ##Creating second_len which has length of 2nd field.
  next                                                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  val=""                                                           ##Nullifying next statements from here.
  match($0,/\/\/.*/)                                               ##Using match function to match from // to till end of line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                                    ##Creating val which has sub string of matched regex.
  $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)                                         ##Keeping everything before matched regex in current line.
  printf("%-"first_len"s\t\t%-"second_len"s\t\t%s\n",$1,$2,val)    ##Printing spaces appropriately after fields to even the spaces.
}
' Input_file Input_file                                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***NOTE:*** I have put 2 tabs in output, in case you want single tab(alignment per columns is already fixed) then change from `\t\t` to `\t` in above printf statement.

Comment: How did you end up with 2 input_files?

Comment: @CuriousSam, sure, first Input_file gets highest length of 1st and 2nd field and adds spaces as per that while reading it second time, to keep the spaces even in output then adding simple TABs in output, please do let me know in case of any queries here.

Comment: @CuriousSam, I believe this would have worked fine for you, kindly do let me know on same.

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU awk` and `column`, provided you know some character that cannot occur in the input, say `\034` for example. Also, it assumes that first two columns cannot have space character, as inferred from the sample input shown in the question.

```
awk -v FPAT='//.*$|[^ ]+' -v OFS='\034' '{$1=$1} 1' ip.txt | column -s$'\034' -t
```

- Here `FPAT` is used to define the pattern for field contents. `//.*$` will get everything from `//` to end of the line. `[^ ]+` defines the field contents for first two fields.
- `-v OFS='\034'` will set some character that isn't present in the input as the output field separator
- `{$1=$1} 1` rebuid the contents of `$0` and print
- `column -s$'\034' -t` will neatly align the output based on `\034` field separator

Comment: All words after the double forward slashes are also in columns. They should not be manipulated. It's the definition of the items on the right.

Comment: @CuriousSam did you try it out? everything after `//` will be retained as it is, it will not be manipulated

Answer (score 0):

For pretty output, I would start by trying to reformat your input to satisfy `column -t` using a delimiter. For example, you could just pattern match the first two columns using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) and insert a couple of tab-characters where appropriate:

```
sed 's%^\([^ ]*\) *\([^ ]*\) *%\1\t\2\t%' config.txt | column -Lts$'\t'
```

For a more robust solution though, consider using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and the [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) function. This can limit the number of elements returned (using the 'maxsplit' arg) making it super simple to join up again with a tab-character. Put the following in a file called `format_config.py`:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write('\t'.join(line.strip().split(None, 2)) + '\n')
```

Then:

```
python format_config.py < config.txt | column -Lts$'\t'
```